# Android screen size

Tags: android, netbeans, android-virtual-device

I have project in Netbeans that the screen size is QVGA-L (240X320)
and running AVD in WVGA800 (480X800)
first of all I'm not sure what is the different between the two.
but  my real problem is that the actual screen size is 213X270
although that when i put this code :

```
WindowManager windowManager = getWindowManager();
Display defaultDisplay = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
width  = defaultDisplay.getWidth();
height  = defaultDisplay.getHeight();
```

width = 240
height = 320

but again when i press the right buttom corner 
i get from the MotionEvent of the onTouchListener 213X270

what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you're not accounting for the notification bar up top and the application title bar. If you have a default layout set for your app that has an id of main in your res/layout/filename.xml, you can try using this instead:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);
int width = layout.getWidth();
int height= layout.getHeight();
```

Comment: no (0,0) is below the bars. and i'm not using the XML layout i do layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but maybe you need to get the application context instead of the local context.

```
Context context = myContext.getApplicationContext();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay(); 
width  = defaultDisplay.getWidth();
height  = defaultDisplay.getHeight();
```

I'm very interested to see how this turns out, since I have similar code in my own app.  :-) So, better go play with this later myself.